# SQLite Cordova - Error processing SQL: 5

Tags: sql, sqlite, cordova

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "userData", 200000);
console.log(db);
db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);

function populateDB(tx) {
   tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, api_key TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL)');
   tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO USER (api_key, username) VALUES ( "asd", row")');
}

function errorCB(err) {
    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.message);
}

function successCB() {
    console.log("success!");
}
```

First SQL statements executes, but then the second one returns:

```
could not prepare statement (1 unrecognized token: "")")  //with error code 5
```

. Any ideas why?

I am following the PhoneGap Docs at [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html)

Comment: Why are you logging the `code` number instead of the `message`?

Comment: @CL: Edited now. Error code seems more helpful than error itself :P

Comment: I did not ask for `err` itself.

Comment: ah! changing to err.message gives could not prepare statement (1 unrecognized token: "")")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forge the opening quote of the `row` string.

Comment: true! just saw it now. At least I learned something about error Objects in JS. Thanks!